# How do you make camera HTML's background?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, wikitude

The thing is, I use the Wikitude framework, but a lot of things are not compatible, I only use the Wikitude in the architect world, so I was wondering how to achieve this effect, which is the HTML background set to camera, hope to get your help  This is the background effect I want to achieve SOS[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bwxwb.jpg)

The effect I want to achieve is the same as in the picture. I want to do something on the camera when I call the camera, for example, add overlay

I want to implement the effect in the picture below, but it's on the mobile terminal, and it's the rear camera[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLRmn.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can't have the camera as a background (css background).After you access the Camera API, you will get an HTML video element and you have to style it in such a way that it will look like a background.

```
video {
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  object-fit:cover;
  z-index:-1;
  position:absolute;
}
```

The user will also need to give the permissions to open the camera.

I've created a pen [here](https://codepen.io/florinsimion/pen/yoOZbp)

Comment: This effect is exactly what I want to achieve. But my project is a App, I do not know whether the phone camera can call.

Comment: That's great. I just want to make this happen, but I want it on my phone, and it's a rear camera. I don't know, OK? My friend gave you the best regards